# Optimize full outer join query

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

The following outer join query takes more than 10 minutes to produce the results, How can I optimize further, Is there a way I can avoid full outer join?

Any help would be really appreciated,

thanks

```
    WITH CMD_DEP AS (
SELECT
    DEPLOYMENT_ID
FROM
    CMD_DEPLOYMENT
WHERE
    ORG_ID = 'xyz'
    AND DEPLOYMENT_DATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2013-02-11 13:03:36.928000' AND TIMESTAMP '2020-02-11 13:03:36.928000'
    AND TYPE NOT IN ('PROOF',
    'TEST') )
SELECT
    COALESCE(opens.UA_DEVICE,
    clicks.UA_DEVICE) deviceType,
    COALESCE(opens.OPENS,
    0) opens,
    COALESCE(clicks.CLICKS,
    0) clicks
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        o.UA_DEVICE,
        SUM(o.HTTP_OPEN_CNT) OPENS
    FROM
        AGG_DPLYMNT_OPEN_DEVICE_TOTALS o,
        CMD_DEP cmd_dep
    WHERE
        cmd_dep.DEPLOYMENT_ID = o.DEPLOYMENT_ID
    GROUP BY
        o.UA_DEVICE) opens
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        c.UA_DEVICE,
        SUM(c.HTTP_REDIRECT_CNT) CLICKS
    FROM
        AGG_DPLYMNT_CLICK_DEVICE_TOTAL c,
        CMD_DEP cmd_dep
    WHERE
        cmd_dep.DEPLOYMENT_ID = c.DEPLOYMENT_ID
    GROUP BY
        c.UA_DEVICE) clicks ON
    opens.UA_DEVICE = clicks.UA_DEVICE;
```

Comment: Why are you mixing archaic comma-based joins with correct, standard `JOIN` syntax? An outer join may not be necessary.  You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want.

Comment: run an explain plan and post results

Comment: @OldProgrammer how to run that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use union all instead of outer join.

```
            WITH CMD_DEP AS (
SELECT
    DEPLOYMENT_ID
FROM
    CMD_DEPLOYMENT
WHERE
    ORG_ID = '05321f3b-5937-4394-8d10-0eb91ae76562'
    AND DEPLOYMENT_DATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2013-02-11 13:03:36.928000' AND TIMESTAMP '2020-02-11 13:03:36.928000'
    AND TYPE NOT IN ('PROOF',
    'TEST') )
SELECT
    UA_DEVICE deviceType ,
    sum(OPENS) opens ,
    sum(CLICKS) clicks
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        UA_DEVICE,
        HTTP_OPEN_CNT AS opens,
        0 AS clicks
    FROM
        AGG_DPLYMNT_OPEN_DEVICE_TOTALS c,
        CMD_DEP cmd_dep
    WHERE
        cmd_dep.DEPLOYMENT_ID = c.DEPLOYMENT_ID
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        UA_DEVICE,
        0 ,
        HTTP_REDIRECT_CNT
    FROM
        AGG_DPLYMNT_CLICK_DEVICE_TOTAL o,
        CMD_DEP cmd_dep
    WHERE
        cmd_dep.DEPLOYMENT_ID = o.DEPLOYMENT_ID )
GROUP BY
    UA_DEVICE ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(opens.UA_DEVICE,
    clicks.UA_DEVICE) deviceType,
    COALESCE(opens.OPENS,
```

to

```
SELECT /*+ gather_plan_statistics */
    COALESCE(opens.UA_DEVICE,
    clicks.UA_DEVICE) deviceType,
    COALESCE(opens.OPENS,
```

and then run the SQL. Once it finishes, then run this:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST'))
```

You get a plan report plus Actuals versus Estimates plus timings. That gives a great starting point to see where the issues are, or you can post it back here for assistance

Comment: SQL_ID  5rsm4y10jd4p2, child number 0
BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE(:1 , :2 ); END;
NOTE: cannot fetch plan for SQL_ID: 5rsm4y10jd4p2, CHILD_NUMBER: 0
      Please verify value of SQL_ID and CHILD_NUMBER; 
      It could also be that the plan is no longer in cursor cache (check v$sql_plan)

Comment: You have serverout output turned on, so we picked up that instead.  You need to do it again with serveroutput off

Comment: How do I turn off?

Comment: set serverout off

Answer (score 2):

The query looks okay (in spite of the 1890s joins). So it's indexes you use to speed up access. The rows you look at are limited by the criteria on `cmd_deployment`. So start with this index:

```
create index idx1 on cmd_deployment(org_id, deployment_date, type, deployment_id);
```

This assumes that `org_id` is the most limiting factor here. It may as well be `deployment_date`, in which case you'd make this column first. Or just create both indexes and see which is used.

```
create index idx1b on cmd_deployment(deployment_date, org_id, type, deployment_id);
```

From there you get to the other tables via

```
create index idx2 on agg_dplymnt_open_device_totals(deployment_id, ua_device, http_open_cnt);
create index idx3 on agg_dplymnt_click_device_total(deployment_id, ua_device, http_redirect_cnt);
```

As to your query, you *may* pick up speed by materializing the ad hoc view for the query:

```
WITH CMD_DEP AS (
SELECT /*+MATERIALIZE*/
    DEPLOYMENT_ID
```

Answer (score -2):

To optimize the queries. Please find below steps,

1. Avoid using CTE
2. Avoid using Sub Queries, Instead use Table Variable to fetch the required data
3. Check if you can apply WHERE condition on Integer column instead of VARCHAR column.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting these ideas from or what platform you are doing your testing on. You don't offer any reasons why you should avoid these approaches or provide sources for your reasoning. And you're wrong.

Comment: Database Optimizer (regardless of what database you are using) can not always properly optimize such query (with subqueries). In this case, the problem to the optimizer is to choose the right way to join result sets. There are several algorithms for joining two result sets. The choice of the algorithm depends on the number of records which are contained in one and in the other result set. In case if you join two physical tables (subquery is not a physical table), the database can easily determine the amount of data in two result sets by the available statistics.

Comment: Hi Sanjay. You made three points. This is an Oracle specific question. If Oracle fails to optimise a sub query correctly then that is either because of a lack of statistics or a bug with the optimiser. The first one can be managed the second needs to have an SR created with a use case and fixed. Sub Queries can make code clearer and in some instance result in plan optimisations. They should not be avoided just their use and benefits understood. You also suggest avoid using CTE. Why? And your suggestion in number 3 is just plain wrong.